# Android Fragment forgets button

Tags: android, button, null, fragment

My fragment initializes the button, i can see that in the debugger.
When i call the method setButtonText from the activity that has the fragment in it's layout, the button becomes null. I've looked on the internet but so far i didn't found any solution

```
public class PrepareTrainingFragment extends Fragment
{
private Button button;
private TextView tv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preparetrainingfragment, container, false);
    button=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ptfragmentbtn);
    Log.w("button init","button init");
    return v;
}

public void setButtonText(String text)
{
    button.setText(text);
}
```

in the class that encapsulates the fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION); //hide navigation bar temporarily


    driverFragment=new PrepareTrainingFragment();


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, driverFragment);

    driverFragment.setButtonText("hello");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

A FragmentTransaction is not executed in real time, you have to call boolean result = fragmentTransaction.executePendingTransactions(); before updating your button. Also, why dont you update the button within your Fragment ?

Comment: cause the text on the button needs to be changed sometimes from within other classes

Comment: And does executePendingTransactions solve the problem ?

Comment: nope it doesn't, btw isn't it fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()?
I just want to use the fragment for reusabilty of the code in it...

Comment: Does your activity have an interface by which it communicates to the fragment?

Comment: Try that to pass around messages.  One caveat: this will make your fragment dependent on the activity, something that is not a recommended design.  I got my fragments talking to each other that way.

Comment: Guess i'll wait, it really should work it's rlly strange. I don't like dependancy's that much